# WordPress custom posts section

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I'm trying to create an extra content area that is similar to the default posts WordPress provides. My outcome is to loop these posts on a page without needing WordPress default posts as they will be used for my blog.

**I've setup the admin area to create posts and it's displayed into my theme but I'm having trouble. It's only displaying the recent post, instead of looping all posts**

I used a guide that helped me build this. [adding editable areas](http://vocecommunications.com/blog/2010/06/adding-editable-content-areas-to-your-wordpress-theme/) which may help you guys understand.

**Anyone know how to fix it, so it displays all posts, not just the most recent?**

my code so far:

**example-page.php**

```
<p>   
  <?php $content_block = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'content-block', 
  'posts_per_page'=>10, 'content-position'=>'about-bottom'))?>
  <?php if($content_block->have_posts()): $content_block->the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content();?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

**functions.php**

```
function initialize_content_blocks()  {
  register_post_type('content-block', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Page Content ',
      'singular_name' => 'Content Block',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Content Block',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Content Block',
      'new_item' => 'New Content Block',
      'view_item' => 'View Content Block',
      'search_items' => 'Search Content Blocks',
      'not_found' => 'No content_blocks found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No content blocks found in Trash',
      'view' => 'View Content Block'
    ),
    'publicly_queryable' => false, 
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => false, 
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
    'taxonomies' => array()
  ));

  register_taxonomy('content-position', array('content-block'), array(
  'rewrite' => false,
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Content Positions',
    'singular_name' => 'Content Position',
    'search_items' => 'Search Content Positions',
    'popular_items' => 'Popular Content Positions',
    'all_items' => 'All Content Positions',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Content Position',
    'update_item' => 'Update Content Position',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Content Position',
    'new_item_name' => 'New Tag Content Position'
  ),
  'show_tagcloud' => false,
  'hierarchical' => true
));

}
add_action('init', 'initialize_content_blocks');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you missed the actual looping. And it is also good to reset your custom query. Add wp_reset_postdata() after your code.

```
$content_block = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'content-block' ... ));

if( $content_block->have_posts() )
{
    while( $content_block->have_posts() )
    {
        $content_block->the_post();
        the_content();
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: i had to slightly adjust some of your code as wordpress uses different syntax  but it works now. thanks for showing code.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the actual looping through the results, see example in [`have_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts) documentation.

Notice `while ( have_posts() )` call. This will make the WordPress loop through all the posts in the query.

Comment: would you be able write the code with the while loop in? i'm having trouble